# Insertion sorting

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I'm writing a program to order a list of numbers using insertion sorting and there's something I'm not understanding.

```
    int[] a = { 5, 3, 8, 2, 1 };

     for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
     {
         int key = a[i];
         int j = i +1;
         int nextElement = a[j];

             if (nextElement < key)
             {
                 swap(ref nextElement, ref key); 
             }
             else
             {

             }
     }
     for (int i =0;i<a.Length;i++)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("{0}", a[i]);
     }
 }

 static void swap(ref int x, ref int y)
 {
     int temp;
     temp = x;
     x = y;
     y = temp;
 }
```

This is what I've written thus far, but I'm having trouble actually understanding how to implement the algorithm. Does it just look at the previous elements and sort an element into them?

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code. Instead, copy the code and paste it into the post directly. You should describe in more detail what you're having trouble with as well if you want people to actually respond

Comment: What specifically is the problem?  It's unclear what your code is doing or not doing correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are swapping `nextElement` and `key` instead of `a[i]` and `a[j]`. 
`Int` is a [value type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx), in your case `nextElement` equals to `a[i]`, but if you change `nextElement` - `a[i]` value won't be changed.

So you need to swap `a[i]` and `a[j]`.

```
if (a[i] > a[j]) {swap (ref a[i], ref a[j]); }
```

Or just make swap function take array and indexes to swap as parameters

```
void swap (int a[], int i, int j) 
{
    int temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = temp;
}
```

And then you can swap numbers using

```
if (a[i] > a[j]) {swap (a, i, j);}
```

Comment: Surely if I am assigning nextElement and key to a[i] and a[j] respectively, it doesn't matter?

Comment: @Ed_4434 `int` is a value type, so nextElemet's value is equal to `a[i]` value, but if you change `nextElemnt` `a[i]` won't be changed.

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Ed_4434 You are welcome. I strongly recommend to read/google about difference between value types and reference types.

Answer (score 0):

## include

```
int main()
{
    int i=0,j=0,k=0,l=0,key=0;
    int a[20];

    printf("Enter the Elements to be sorted\n");
    for (l=0;l<=5;l++)
      {

          scanf("%d", &a[l]);
      }
    printf("the value of l is %d", l);
    printf("The Entered array elements are \n");
    for(k=0;k<l;k++)
      {
          printf("%d",a[k]);
      }


    for(j=1;j<l;j++)
      {
          key= a[j];
          i= j-1;
          while (i>=0 & a[i]>key)
               {
                    a[i+1] = a[i];
                    i=i-1;
               }

          a[i+1]=key;
      }
   printf("The Sorted array is \n");
   for (l=0;l<6;l++)
      {

          printf("%d", a[l]);
      }
```

}